# How to implement nested datatables with unlimited depth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, nested-datalist

I need datatables that can have nested rows dynamically created based on the data.

Something like this but with unlimited nested rows:
https://jsfiddle.net/dyv4L8bp/4/

Here is the code I have tried so far (taken from an example I found):

```
function fnFormatDetails(table_id, html) {
    var sOut = "<table id=\"exampleTable_" + table_id + "\">";
    sOut += html;
    sOut += "</table>";
    return sOut;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// EXTERNAL DATA - Array of Objects 

var terranImage = "https://i.imgur.com/HhCfFSb.jpg"; 
var jaedongImage = "https://i.imgur.com/s3OMQ09.png";
var grubbyImage = "https://i.imgur.com/wnEiUxt.png";
var stephanoImage = "https://i.imgur.com/vYJHVSQ.jpg";
var scarlettImage = "https://i.imgur.com/zKamh3P.jpg";

// DETAILS ROW A 
var detailsRowAPlayer1 = { pic: jaedongImage, name: "Jaedong", team: "evil geniuses", server: "NA" };
var detailsRowAPlayer2 = { pic: scarlettImage, name: "Scarlett", team: "acer", server: "Europe" };
var detailsRowAPlayer3 = { pic: stephanoImage, name: "Stephano", team: "evil geniuses", server: "Europe" };
                         
var detailsRowA = [ detailsRowAPlayer1, detailsRowAPlayer2, detailsRowAPlayer3 ];

// DETAILS ROW B 
var detailsRowBPlayer1 = { pic: grubbyImage, name: "Grubby", team: "independent", server: "Europe" };
                         
var detailsRowB = [ detailsRowBPlayer1 ];
                    
// DETAILS ROW C 
var detailsRowCPlayer1 = [{ pic: terranImage, name: "Bomber", team: "independent", server: "NA" }];
                         

var rowA = { race: "Zerg", year: "2014", total: "3", details: detailsRowA};
var rowB = { race: "Protoss", year: "2014", total: "1", details: detailsRowB};
var rowC = { race: "Terran", year: "2014", total: "1", details: detailsRowCPlayer1};

var newRowData = [rowA, rowB, rowC] ;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var iTableCounter = 1;
    var oTable;
    var oInnerTable;
    var detailsTableHtml;

    //Run On HTML Build
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        // you would probably be using templates here
        detailsTableHtml = $("#detailsTable").html();

        //Insert a 'details' column to the table
        var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
        var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
        nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">';
        nCloneTd.className = "center";

        $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function () {
            this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
        });

        $('#exampleTable tbody tr').each(function () {
            this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
        });
        
       
        //Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
        var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aaData": newRowData,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                   "mDataProp": null,
                   "sClass": "control center",
                   "sDefaultContent": '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">'
                },
                { "mDataProp": "race" },
                { "mDataProp": "year" },
                { "mDataProp": "total" }
            ],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
            },
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
        });

        /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
        * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
        * rather it is done here
        */
        $('#exampleTable tbody td img').live('click', function () {
            var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            var nTds = this;
            
            if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                /* This row is already open - close it */
                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            }
            else {
                /* Open this row */
                var rowIndex = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(nTds).closest('tr')[0] ); 
                var detailsRowData = newRowData[rowIndex].details;
               
                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
                oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, detailsTableHtml), 'details');
                oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "aaData": detailsRowData,
                    "bSort" : true, // disables sorting
                    "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "pic" },
                    { "mDataProp": "name" },
                    { "mDataProp": "team" },
                    { "mDataProp": "server" }
                ],
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
                    },
                    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                      var imgLink = aData['pic']; 
                      var imgTag = '<img width="100px" src="' + imgLink + '"/>';
                      $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(imgTag);  
                     return nRow;
                    }
                });
                iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
            }
        });


    });
```

Can someone send me an example. Please dont send examples with a single nested row only. I need unlimited ones.

Comment: Have you considered a different approach, based on a [tree structure](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+tree+sortable+site:stackoverflow.com), which may better suit the nested data structure you want to display? There may be reasons why you don't want (or cannot implement) that - but it may help to clarify those reasons.

Comment: I expect you could recursively build dynamic DataTables within dynamic DataTables - but that feels like a fairly broad programming assignment. Can you narrow it down to a specific problem you may be facing with your current code?

Comment: @andrewJames I have thought about tree structure but thats not how I want it to look. I need to paginate, search through list, and show headers just like in a datatable. Do you think its doable? If yes can you send a link of an example?

Comment: @andrewJames found this example which is exactly what I need, however, I dont know how to make it work without using Ajax, I just want to use array variables. https://jsfiddle.net/3Lkm8qbv/22/

Comment: Very nice! - But that does not do what you asked for. (a) It has 3 hard-coded levels. You asked for the depth to have "_unlimited nested rows_". (b) It has fixed row layouts at each level. You asked for each layout to be "_dynamically created based on the data_". (c) There are no table headings in the lower levels. You want to "_show headers_". (d) There is no pagination or searching in the lower levels. You wanted it to be "_just like in a datatable_". There is a big difference in code complexity between these approaches.

Comment: @andrewJames (a) this example has 3 levels only but I can run it inside a loop so levels will be created depending on the data. (b) layout is fixed in the example but inside a loop I can just increase the left margins for ex. for each level and thus make it appear more in the right side. (c) I dont want headers for the lower levels, only for the main row. (d) I dont want pagination for the lower levels, only for the main level.

Comment: OK - thank you for the clarifications (you should add those to the question). In that case, you are almost home. If you want to migrate from using Ajax to using array variables, you will need to use the [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option. This can use a _single_ JavaScript variable as the table's data source - so you will need to create a _single_ JavaScript object which contains all the data you need. In other words, your source data needs to be nested, in the same way that your table's data will be nested.

Comment: (And, by the way, you can use tree structures to implement this. Each node of the tree can show whatever you want - including tabular data.)